# Automator: Change modification date of selected finder items

Tags: date, automator, finder

I want to create an automator service to change the modification date of the selected finder files to the current date. Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Automator service :

Set the popups to "**Files or folders**" in "**Finder**"

Add the "**Run Shell Script**" action, set the popups to "**/bin/bash**" and "**as arguments**".

Put this script in the action :

```
d=$(date  "+%Y%m%d%H%M.%S") ## the formatted current date
touch -t $d "$@" ## change the file's modification date
```

Save the workflow, that's all.